# does mediaelement.js reads HLS? or .m3u8?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have an application on NetGear, build with html5 and javascript, the application streams live tv, HLS or m3u8 files.

i was wondering if mediaelement.js is suitable for this kind of applications.

Answer (score 1):

mediaelement is now capable to play HLS based streams: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/commit/b7f88a9f8452edb4e31cb98a218a0b1c4c7a7af9